# Emacs tide format javascript configuration only on edited lines

Tags: javascript, emacs, tslint

I've had tide running on my JS files for a long time. I'm part of a bigger project, and I seldom edit other peoples files, but occasionally I do.

I've had the below hook enabled i emacs, since it is a very nice feature:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'tide-format-before-save)
```

Problem is that this can mess up other peoples formatting throughout the file when I only edit 1 single line, and then save. So when pushing to git after the editing there is huge diff of changes (whitespace, all of them off course).

Is it possible to get tide to format only the lines I've edited?
Or alternatively somehow get tide to only format as I type and only where I do my typing/changes?

I've searched the web for a solution for quite a while but have not succeeded in finding a solution. Am I stuck with just disabling the auto-format feature?

Used emacs for more than 20 years now, so reluctant to change editor :-)
(I'm still, after 20 years, horrible at understanding/writing lisp...)